# Two-Sample Hypothesis Test for Difference Between Two Proportions: Pooled vs Unpooled? How to Choose?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, pooling

**When** are you supposed to use the *pooled* formula vs the *unpooled* formula? My understanding is that you use the *pooled* formula when testing a hypothesis where the null hypothesis is $H_0 = 0$ and the alternative hypothesis is $H_0 \ne 0$. My confusion arises when doing hypothesis testing for "greater than" or "less than" scenarios.  Do you pool it to create a ${\hat{p}}$ or do you use ${p_1}$ and ${p_2}$ seen in the *unpooled* formula below?

Which formula would I use if I were testing:

$H_0 = 0$

$H_a \gt 0$

Or:

$H_0 = 0$

$H_a \lt 0$

Or other scenarios like:

$H_0 \ge n$

$H_a \lt n$

Or:

$H_0 \le n$

$H_a \gt n$

**Pooled Formula**:

$z = \dfrac{({p_1} - {p_2}) - d_0}{\sqrt{\hat{p} (1-\hat{p}) \left(\dfrac{1}{n_1} + \dfrac{1}{n_2} \right)}}$

Where $\hat{p} = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2}{n_1 + n_2}$

**Unpooled Formula**:

$z = \dfrac{({p_1} - {p_2}) - d_0}{\sqrt{\dfrac{{p_1}(1-{p_1})}{n_1} + \dfrac{{p_2}(1-{p_2})}{n_2}}}$

Where ${p_1}$ and ${p_2}$ are simply the proportions in decimal format.

---

I see so many confusing posts on this subject:

[1] [Video maker tests null=0, alternative>0 and uses pooled](https://youtu.be/AHQHWXByLM8?t=9m3s)

[2] [This StackExchange post suggests there is not a consensus among stats practicioners](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17195/is-there-a-reference-that-legitimises-the-use-of-the-unpooled-z-test-to-compare)

[3] [This StackExchange post suggests you use unpooled when you "believe" the population proportions are different](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/hypothesis-testing-for-2-proportions-for-a-b-testing/126793) - I have a problem with the word "believe" as I'm looking for a concrete definitive rule to guide my decision framework.

[4] [Makes the case that pooled estimates give us the best estimate for variability](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/members/courses/teachers_corner/49013.html) - but doesn't have examples of "greater than" or "less than" scenarios which makes it hard for me to understand

[5] [StackExchange post provides good examples of the difference in calculation but also states 'the final statistical decision does not quite exist on this'](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126726/hypothesis-testing-for-2-proportions-for-a-b-testing/126793)

[6] [YouTube video showing a two proportion left-tail z-test](https://youtu.be/xteObwaYrF0?t=6m3s) - Video maker uses pooled formula when $H_a \lt 0$ .

[7] [YouTube video shows using pooled formula in one-sided test](https://youtu.be/SW391zvBgCI?t=29m35s)

[8] [YouTube video computes $\hat{p}$ but uses in unpooled formula](https://youtu.be/hYhzdltam9Y?t=1m45s)

[9] [Blog writer uses unpooled formula to calculate the standard error for a one-tailed test](http://blog.excelmasterseries.com/2014/05/2-sample-unpooled-hypothesis-test-of.html)

... I'll stop there.

---

**Edit (1 year later)**:

Here's another example. There's a popular online tool that is often referenced as the "go-to" source for A/B testing between two-sample proportions.

Their tool **doesn't** pool but all over the page they are referencing the DIFFERENCE... which to me, implies a null hypothesis of no difference in which case they should be using a pooled estimate.

Example:

```
s1 = 5
n1 = 1023

s2 = 4
n2 = 344

p1 = s1 / n1
p2 = s2 / n2

# abtestguide.com calculation of z-score
z_unpooled = (p1 - p2) / (((p1*(1-p1))/n1) + ((p2*(1-p2))/n2))**0.5

# pooled calculation of z-score
p = (s1 + s2) / (n1 + n2)
z_pooled = (p1 - p2) / (p*(1-p)*((1/n1)+(1/n2)))**0.5

print('Unpooled: {:.6f}, Pooled: {:.6f}'.format(z_unpooled, z_pooled))
# Unpooled: -1.091082, Pooled: -1.337244
```

Can anyone help clarify when to use pooled vs unpooled? I've read to use pooled unless you have a good reason not to. I've also read that you use unpooled when testing for "better" or "worse" criteria. It's so unclear to me.

Comment: Usually we write something like $H_o: \theta = \theta_o$ versus $H_1: \theta \ne \theta_o$ for some well-defined parameter $\theta$. Writing $H_o = 0$ does not look right.

Comment: Feel free to edit. *theta* doesn't mean anything to me and 0 makes more sense since we're saying there is no difference between two samples so the difference equals zero.

Comment: I'm also trying to find answers for this question. Here's a paper that might help.
https://ijpam.eu/contents/2013-89-4/5/5.pdf

Comment: I think that the pooled is used when you assume equal variances